# session_destroy não inicializa nova sessão

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando usar o código abaixo para quando o usuário clicar em sair, ele for redirecionado para o arquivo abaixo de destruir a sessão, porém depois de destruída a sessão não é possível logar novamente, porque a página a seguir após o login não carrega, só aparece o nome da próxima página na barra de endereço.

Página que contém as funções de login:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['usuariosession'] = $user;
$_SESSION['senhasession'] = $pass;
$_SESSION['autenticandosession'] = true;

header('Location:views/painel.php/');
```

Próxima página após o login:

```
session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['autenticandosession']) || $_SESSION['autenticandosession'] != true){
        echo "Acesso não autorizado </br>";
        echo "Por favor faça seu login <a href='login.php'> clicando aqui </a>";
        exit();
    }else{
        echo "<p> Bem vindo ".ucfirst($_SESSION['usuariosession'])."</p> </br>";
    }


<html>
<head> 
    <title> Painel </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> Olá eu sou o painel, se voce chegou até aqui é porque suas credenciais deram certo... </h1>

    <a href="../sair.php"> Sair </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Página com a função para sair:

```
session_start();

    unset ($_SESSION['usuariosession']);

    unset ($_SESSION['senhasession']);

    session_destroy();
    header('Location:views/login.php/');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No login.php você está redirecionando pra `/view/painel.php` e no sair.php está direcionando para `views/login.php`. E não existe login.php nesse diretório view.